# Is it possible to autopause Clementine on Skype call?

Tags: skype, clementine

There is the bash command `clementine --pause`, but what should I put in a bash script as the `if` condition to pause Clementine during a Skype call?

Comment: Could you add the prototype of the script you are creating?

Comment: @M.Becerra Sorry, I'm not a developer, but a beginner: I don't have created a script.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Skype
2. Go to **Options** → **Notifications**
3. Select a notification to modify, like **Incoming Call Ringing**
4. Under **Execute the following script**, put in the command

[Source](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/270810-need-script-autopause-clementine-skype-call.html?posted=1#post302991134)